# Twig file path for twig-extends

Tags: symfony, twig, extends

There are two twig files **src/MyVendor/MyBundle/Resources/views/MyApp/layout.html.twig** and **src/MyVendor/MyBundle/Resources/views/MyApp/myView.html.twig**.

The content of **src/MyVendor/MyBundle/Resources/views/MyApp/myView.html.twig**

```
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
   view content is here.
{% endblock %}
```

But I am getting an error

```
Unable to find template "layout.html.twig" in
"MyVendorMyBundle:MyApp:myView.html.twig"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do it as following:

```
{% extends "MyVendorMyBundle:MyApp:layout.html.twig" %}
```

You can find more details in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/templating.html#including-other-templates)

Comment: they hide, they really hide the fact, that you HAVE to to extend from subfolders like this `AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:User/index.html.twig` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514643/including-the-twig-file-from-a-subdirectory