# Including the twig file from a subdirectory

Tags: symfony, twig

I've got a problem - I can't include a twig file in another twig file when it's placed in the subdirectory. Example:

I've got a file `AppUserBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig` (symfony path is `src/App/UserBundle/Resorcues/views/Dashboard/index.html.twig` and so are the other views' paths).
In that file I've got include for a file `Status.html.twig` placed in `AppUserBundle:Dashboard:User` subdirectory. But when trying to include it I'm getting message 'can't find template'.

```
{% include 'AppUserBundle:Dashboard:User:Status.html.twig' %}
```

When I move the Status.html.twig file to `AppUserBundle:Dashboard` directory and include it everything works just fine. Can I somehow get to any file like that?

```
AppUserBundle:Dashboard:Subdir:file
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome` is just a logical controller name, the `:` doesn't mean a `/`. This logical name refers to the `@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/views/Welcome` directory where `@AcmeDemoBundle` is a logical bundle name which become something like `src/Acme/DemoBundle`.

If you want to add another directory to the name, just place it after the logical name as you normally do:

```
AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:User/index.html.twig
```

This refers to the `src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Welcome/User/index.html.twig` file.

Comment: It worked for me only with colons, so maybe it has to be AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:User:index.html.twig